# How to enter password for an operation requiring root privileges via SSH?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm writing a bash script that creates a new user on a remote server (running Debian). The script is supposed to be run on a local machine by a person who has an account on the server, and the account is added to sudoers. The person's account on the server is also set up to support SSH connections.

The scripts look like this:

```bash
# local script
ssh -p 22 ${my_user_name}@${server_host} 'sudo -S bash -s' < remote-actions.sh ${new_user_name}
```

```bash
# remote-actions.sh
useradd $1 # Requires sudo
```

Running local script, an SSH connection is successfully established. Then terminal prompts for `my_user_name`'s password:

```
[sudo] password for my_user_name:
```

In a couple seconds, it prints an error. It's definitely impossible to enter a password within two seconds.

```
[sudo] password for my_user_name: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for my_user_name:
```

And so on until it prints:

```
[sudo] password for my_user_name: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for my_user_name: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for my_user_name: sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Is there a way to increase the delay for password input or somehow else overcome this problem?

Comment: It's not reading from your terminal at all.  It's reading from the stdin you supplied.  Add your password as the first line of the file.

Comment: Is remote-actions.sh really just that one `useradd` command? If so, just use `ssh -p 22 ${my_user_name}@${server_host} sudo useradd ${new_user_name}`. The problem happens because input is redirected from the script file, so if you remove the redirect, you remove the problem.

Comment: Why do you use `-S` for `sudo`, if you want the password being entered manually?